# Why does addEventListener work with function() but not with a specific function I pass?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Why does `addEventListener` work with `function()` in the commented code but not with a specific function I pass?

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");  

// button.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
// button.classList.toggle("bigyellow"); 
// });  

button.addEventListener("click", toggleMe);  
function toggleMe(){    
    this.classList.toggle("big-yellow"); 
}


//CSS:
//.bigyellow {

//  background-color: #ffff66; /* yellow */
//}
```

Comment: Works fine for me.... But you really should declare your function before you reference it and not rely on hoisting.

Comment: @Cruiser - `this` inside `toggleMe` *should* be the button that was clicked

Comment: oh dear .... `toggle("bigyellow");` !== `toggle("big-yellow");`

Comment: Guys thank you so much! Yes, I was calling the function before declaring it, hence the problem. The Css was correct, but I copied the name of the class wrong here. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Your ***this*** is probably referencing a global object as it's inside a function (that is probably a "window"), so you can try to save the name/caller-id/this of the button before entering into the function to know which button to reference inside it.

For some inside how this works in JavaScript, check:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this